# How to iterate rows between start_date and end_date in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

[image: Original Data]

And here is the output I'm hoping for.

[image: Desired Output]

Comment: Please add a reproducible example with your data

Answer (score 2):

This should work. The key is to use `uncount` from `dplyr` package. Then you need to do some operations regarding the datetime. There are some tricky issues in calculating the difference in months. What I proposed here may not be the best way to do it, but you get the idea.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df = tibble(name = c('Alice', 'Bob', 'Caroline'), 
            start_date = as.Date(c('2019-01-01','2018-03-01','2019-06-01')), 
            end_date = as.Date(c('2019-07-01','2019-05-01','2019-09-01')))

# # A tibble: 3 x 3
# name     start_date end_date  
# <chr>    <date>     <date>    
# 1 Alice    2019-01-01 2019-07-01
# 2 Bob      2018-03-01 2019-05-01
# 3 Caroline 2019-06-01 2019-09-01

df %>% mutate(tenure_in_month = as.integer(difftime(end_date, start_date, units = "days")/365*12+2))%>%
  uncount(tenure_in_month)%>%
  group_by(name)%>%
  mutate(iteratedDate = start_date %m+% months(row_number()-1))%>%
  select(name,iteratedDate)

# A tibble: 28 x 2
# Groups:   name [3]
   name  iteratedDate
   <chr> <date>      
 1 Alice 2019-01-01  
 2 Alice 2019-02-01  
 3 Alice 2019-03-01  
 4 Alice 2019-04-01  
 5 Alice 2019-05-01  
 6 Alice 2019-06-01  
 7 Alice 2019-07-01  
 8 Bob   2018-03-01  
 9 Bob   2018-04-01  
10 Bob   2018-05-01
```

Answer (score 1):

I use `seq` function to fix this problem.

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)

# data 
original_data <- data.table(
    CustomerName = c('Ben','Julie','Angelo','Carlo'),
    StartDate = c(ymd(20190101),ymd(20180103),ymd(20190106),ymd(20170108)),
    EndDate = c(ymd(20190107),ymd(20190105),ymd(20190109),ymd(20180112))
)

#       CustomerName  StartDate    EndDate
#1:          Ben 2019-01-01 2019-01-07
#2:        Julie 2018-01-03 2019-01-05
#3:       Angelo 2019-01-06 2019-01-09
#4:        Carlo 2017-01-08 2018-01-12

finish_data <- original_data %>% 
    .[,.(IteratedDate = seq(from = StartDate,
                            to = EndDate, by = 'day')), by = .(CustomerName)]

#   CustomerName IteratedDate
#1:          Ben   2019-01-01
#2:          Ben   2019-01-02
#3:          Ben   2019-01-03
#4:          Ben   2019-01-04
#5:          Ben   2019-01-05
#6:          Ben   2019-01-06
#7:          Ben   2019-01-07
#8:        Julie   2018-01-03
#9:        Julie   2018-01-04
```